# How can we change the indent of a particular paragraph?

Tags: indentation

https://www.overleaf.com/project/6404a10f7700cdef79536dd4            How can I indent a particular paragraph to right according to my choice to match with the next paragraphs? In my case, the indent of my profile paragraph is not same as indent of education. The margin of the profile paragraphs should be same the margin of education. These two portions start from different positions. Looking forward for your valuable inputs.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What do you mean by saying 'match with the next paragraphs'? Can you provide some details or an illustration?

Comment: From your screenshot, it seems to be an issue with your CV template. It is difficult to diagnose this issue without its code. You may select the core part of the template (defining the style, for instance) to paste to your question or share the template link address :-)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem.. It is impossible to answer without see the code producing this. Reduce your document (text and code) as far as possible, while still showing the problem and still it can be compiled. Then add the remaining text and code  to the question.

Comment: https://www.overleaf.com/project/6404a10f7700cdef79536dd4

Comment: The link is restricted but moreover external links tend to break after some time and anyway, this  discourages  help, specially if the link directs to a large document to debug. Please make a standalone question showing only a MWE.

Comment: If the education part is made with a `tabular` or similar environment, consider using `@{}` at the very left (and right) of your colum speficication, for example `\begin{tabular}{@{}lr@{}}`.

Comment: \cvsection{EDUCATION}

\cvevent
 {\textbf{2015 - ongoing}}
 {Ph. D. - Corneal dystrophy}
 {National Institute of Science Education and Research (NISER) - Bhubaneswar, Odisha (India)}
 {Current Status: Thesis submitted.}
\vfill\null

Comment: \cvsection{Profile}

{Researcher with 7 years of experience in molecular biology and genetics. Expertise in team management, along with guiding masters and project students. Highly skilled in designing experiments, execution, data analysis,and data representation. Passionate about learning new technologies and their applications in different scientific fields}
{}

Comment: One has been prepared by \cvevent but the other has not. I want to start these two para from same margin